# Is it possible to ad a different text in each ad created via Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I want to create a facebook ad for my client and embed a different unique code in each of the text/image. I could not find any such way to automatically achieve that. I am using "https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/" to create my ads.

Answer (score 0):

So you can create different text/image in each ad. 
for unique code you can append url parameters (URL_tags) to the URL on the ad creation flow.